# A simple explanation of common design patterns for non-native English speakers

Tags: php, design-patterns, oop

I am often facing design patterns, and I find most articles explaining them a bit hard to understand, especially since I don't speak English fluently. I would very much appreciate if someone could explain simply and in basic English the following design patterns: Builder, Prototype, Bridge, Composite, Decorator, Facade, Flyweight, Proxy and Observer.

Or if you have any links to good resources, I'm willing to spend the time to try to understand it.

Comment: It would be more productive if you chose *one* of those patterns and told us what part you *don't* understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly, highly, HIGHLY recommend the [Gang of Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_of_Four_(software)) Book.

It is such a good lookup tool for design patterns, although it may be difficult to read if you're not fluent in English.

Here is a list of the design patterns with examples for PHP, you may want to have a look at this:

http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/

Comment: Haha, I think you need to edit the first link because I ended up on an article about a communist faction in China.

Comment: It's fixed now, Stack Overflow didn't like Wikipedia's link too much

Comment: do get the book though, it is the source of all other resources on design patterns. It contains some essential introductions that give more feeling with the subject than sites can give you.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend taking a look at [Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/) as it is a very approachable design patterns book.

There are quite a few [sample pages](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/preview.html) on the O'Reilly website so you can get a good idea of what it's like.

Comment: I cannot recommend this book enough as an intro to design patterns!

Answer (score 2):

That's a lot to ask in one question.  I'd recommend first looking at the Wikipedia articles for each pattern you listed.  [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern), [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern), [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), [Flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), [Proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) and [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  If there's something *specific* about one of the patterns that you don't understand after reading one of those articles, you can always come back here and ask a more focused question.

Next I'd recommend a good *introductory* book on the subject like [Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126/).

Answer (score 0):

G'day,

The GoF book has been translated into many other languages. In fact the first time I saw it was in French, In fact, Wikipedia says into thirteen other languages.

BTW I also vote for looking at the [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book.

HTH

cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [Do Factory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx)